# JSFiddle Running Angular code twice

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

The code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj35xkp9/2/) seems to be running twice.

It's a relatively simple AngularJS app that defines a controller with a keyup listener tied to the enter key of an input, adding the string from $scope.newTag to the $scope.tags array whenever it's pressed.

When I run the code, the expected result would initially be:

```
tag1, tag2
```

But instead, I get:

```
tag1, tag1, tag2, tag2
```

Watching the console also confirms the fact that the code is running twice:

```
Controller checking in...
Controller checking in...
```

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="tagsCtrl">
        <div ng-click="editTags = true;"> <span ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{tag}}, </span>

            <br/>
            <input type="text" ng-show="editTags" ui-keypress="{enter:'keypressCallback($event, doc)'}" ng-model="newTag" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ui.utils"]);

var tagsCtrl = function ($scope) {
    console.log("Controller checking in...");
    $scope.tags = ["tag1", "tag2"];
    $scope.newTag = "";

    $scope.keypressCallback = function ($event) {
        var tagToAdd = $scope.newTag;
        if (tagToAdd === "") {
            $event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            $scope.tags.push(tagToAdd);
            $scope.newTag = "";
            $event.preventDefault();
        }
    };
};

myApp.controller('tagsCtrl', tagsCtrl);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprised there isn't a conflict, but AngularJS is being defined twice.  Once in the Framework & Extentions, and once in the External Resources.

```
Taking one out seems to fix the problem.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jj35xkp9/3/